# Buid apk file from Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I create hello word form Xamarin - Android blank app and set Textview into it. Then, I'm prepare for publish like Xamarin forum tutorial, set Relese, all done!

I'm Archive it to publish apk. I install this apk and then, i open it. It's not display anything, not show Textview "Helloword!", not show anything, it just show background and name of application.

I'm trying to google it but not find anwser, please help me, thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i solved this problem by adding into mainactivities.cs

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```